# Response time different in Postman/Jmeter and web API

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, jmeter, postman

I have an MVC Web aPI and I have trouble in comparing the response time of this API. I added some code to calculate the response time:

In the AuthorizationFilterAttribute OnAuthorization, I have the below code:

```
actionContext.Request.Headers.Add("RequestStartTime", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

I have an ActionFilterAttribute, and an OnActionExecuted in which I have the below code:

```
string strRequestStartTime = actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("RequestStartTime").First();
DateTime dtstartTime = DateTime.Parse(strRequestStartTime);
TimeSpan tsTimeTaken = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtstartTime);
actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("RequestProcessingTime", tsTimeTaken.TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
```

The response has the header "RequestProcessingTime" in milli seconds. The issue is whenever I try the same request using Postman/JMeter, I see that the response time is lesser than what I see in my Response. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the fact the header does not consider time for request to reach the server and response to travel back, my expectation is that it shows only the time, required to process the request on the server side. So JMeter reports time as delta from the time when request has been sent and the time when the last byte has been received, which is more correct in terms of real user experience.

See definitions of "Elapsed Time", "Connect Time" and "Latency" in the [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html). You may also be interested in [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0) article which demonstrates the impact of network capacity on the overall performance

Comment: In this case, JMeter response time should be greater than the server side processing time, right? But, I experience the reverse.